# Clones or duplicate shapes in javafx?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making a Connect 4 game in javafx using Scenebuilder 2.0 for the GUI. 
This is basically what the animation for the chip coming down from top:

```
@FXML
private void click0(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {


    TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(
            Duration.millis(750));
    translate.setToX(1);
    translate.setToY(432);
    ParallelTransition transition = new ParallelTransition(c0,translate);
    transition.setCycleCount(1);
    transition.play();

}
```

This happens when I click the buttons which is directly below all the rows. It isn't nearly complete yet. But how can I have a duplicate of the circle (c0) stay in the original position?

Answer (score 0):

The [Duplicator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.1/docs/api/javafx.fxd/javafx.fxd.Duplicator.html) is not available anymore in the current version.

The only way I found was a dirty hack:

```
Shape.union(c0, c0);
```

... and yes. It's very dirty and not a Circle anymore.

The [answer given here](http://www.eclpeople.com/clone-or-duplicate-shapes-in-javafx-qq-AUvBUMAUivICeoL1jMMd.php) does not fit my needs.